# Generate and Print Training Documents on the Fly

Tags: php

I got some task at hand whereby I have to generate and print training certificates on the fly. The person who's certificate is to be printed will upload his image, add his name and designation and after clicking the print command the certificate will be generated and printed. This module will work on localhost using PHP. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

[mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) or [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Manage html with supplid data from user and parse on the fly.
Of course you are free to output regular html document, not pdf using mentioned libraries.
If you are asking how to build a form to receive data from user - you should start from reading basics - huge variety of variats available...